# Parse XML Envelope in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

I have this response from SOAP:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <env:Body>
  <env:Fault>
   <env:Code>
    <env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value>
    <env:Subcode>
     <env:Value>-10</env:Value>
    </env:Subcode>
   </env:Code>
   <env:Reason>
    <env:Text xml:lang="en">10001069 - Item 804006 not active </env:Text>
   </env:Reason>
   <env:Detail>
    <Object xmlns="">17</Object>
    <ObjectIndex xmlns="">1</ObjectIndex>
    <Command xmlns="">AddObject</Command>
    <SessionID xmlns="">58711</SessionID>
   </env:Detail>
  </env:Fault>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I'd Like to access/know tag `Reason`, like in python: `print ObjectXML.Body.Reason.Text` 
For instance, I want use dot notation for travel inside nodes.
How I do it?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cElement API to get the handle to XML tags in terms of python objects and then use the following activestate recipe to convert the XML to dict representation( Recommended only for smaller XML files, The code in the recipe might need some modifications).

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
import XmlDictConfig as XmlDictConfig

if __name__ == "__main__":
  string_containing_my_xml = "read your XML into a string".
  root = ElementTree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(string_containing_my_xml)).getroot()
  xmldict = XmlDictConfig(root) // XmlDictConfig is available in activestate recipe.
```

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410469-xml-as-dictionary/

Let me know in case anything is unclear to you.